# Finding date range for week for particular month and year

Tags: php

Suppose I have a date available with me: `2016-07`

I want to find date range of Week like this:

```
    2016-07-03 to 2016-07-09
    2016-07-10 to 2016-07-16
    2016-07-17 to 2016-07-23
    2016-07-24 to 2016-07-30
```

How can i achieve this?
I have tried using `MySql` but failed. Now I'm trying to do `php`.

Comment: i have tried in my sql : SELECT
    DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    WEEK(mydate) here my columnname is mydate

Comment: do you want to find only those weeks that fit entirely in the month?

Comment: yes exactly i want the range of week date which falls on that month only

Comment: @Nitin https://eval.in/599789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code should do exactly what you want, if not please tell me or if you have questions

```
$date = "2016-07"; //Your date, can be any given date of this format
$monthAndYear = explode("-", $date);

$weeks = array();

$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthAndYear[1], 1, $monthAndYear[0]);
$start -= 86400; //There are surely better ways

//find beginning if first week
do
{
    $start += 86400;// Add one day
    $tmp = date("N", $start);
}
while($tmp != 1);

//Get all weeks. If you want only those which are in the current month use this instead:
//while(date("n", ($start + 6 * 86400)) == $monthAndYear[1])
while(date("n", $start) == $monthAndYear[1])
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $start);
    $start += (6 * 86400);
    $date .= " to ".date("Y-m-d", $start);
    $weeks[] = $date;
    $start += 86400;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($weeks);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output is this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "2016-07-04 to 2016-07-10"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "2016-07-11 to 2016-07-17"
  [2]=>
  string(24) "2016-07-18 to 2016-07-24"
  [3]=>
  string(24) "2016-07-25 to 2016-07-31"
}
```

With the second `while` option the result will be the same because the 31th is the end of the month and also the end of a week.

Comment: this piece of code not running properly it shows blank page when i try to run can u please look it at and thanx for the help

Comment: Ok, it works just fine, it simply does not output anything. I added three lines to show you the code which outputs the result as well :D

Comment: there is some problem here u have entered 2016-07 but the year in output shows 2007

Comment: Fixed it, my bad. I had the wrong index at this part `mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthAndYear[1], 1, $monthAndYear[0]);` It works now as it should. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: can i ask u one question as u have set index to start week from mon but if i want to do it sun then where i have to make edition in this code.

Comment: Then you have to use this `while($tmp != 7);` instead of `while($tmp != 1);`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Here you can see that the parameter `"N"` gives the weekdays (numeric). 1 represents Monday, 7 represents Sunday. Is this understandable? The while loops basically checks every day from the beginning of the month until it finds tha desired startday (if you want sunday then 7) and starts adding weeks until the end of the month

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code it produces the same output as yours:

```
function weeksRangesOfMonth($month, $year) {

    $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('d', strtotime('First Monday', $start_time)), $year);

    $end_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('t', $start_time), $year);

     $start = date("Y-m-d", $start_time);
     $end = date("Y-m-d", $end_time);

     for($date = $start; $date <= $end; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'))) {

        $time=  strtotime($date);

        $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Last Sunday', $time));
        $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Next Saturday', $time));

        echo "Start: ".$from.", End: ".$to;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

weeksRangesOfMonth(7, 16);
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.org/mWSxphvA